# How can I verify an existing password without Sign in in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my application, I want to re-verify the user's password without having them go through a sign-in process. Therefore, I need code different from the one used for signing in.

I don't want to use this code:

```
var result = _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, password, rememberMe, true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CheckPasswordAsync()` method on the `UserManager` class. Something like:

```
var canSignIn = _signInManager.UserManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password)
```